# How to do conditional check in karate response?

Tags: karate

Is there any way to check if object is empty then ok if not then check if it matches a fixed structure?

I mean, something like:

```
* def expectedDelayEntries = response.delayEntries == "{}" ? {} : '#(delayEntries)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Refer to the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic

Do this in 2 steps.

```
* def expected = condition ? { foo: '#string' } : { bar: '#number' }
* match response == expected
```

Comment: Hi again: even if our answer is an empty node?

Comment: @IgnacioDegeneffe sorry that's hard for me to understand without a proper example.

Comment: Sorry, it was enough with your first answer