# How to handle different response for the same request on Karate api testing?

Tags: api, testing, karate

I have a question about how to handle different responses for the same request in Karate api test. E.g.
The same request:
Given path '/tickets/2000'
When method get
Response:
  1> if ticket #2000 is not expired, then match response = expected result
  2> if ticket #2000 is expired, then matching response.error = 'Ticket is expired'

So how to match the 2 different results. I need to handle both.
Can I use "Try... Catch", how to use it?  Can you give me a syntax example in Karate, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Karate discourages "conditional logic" like this. What I would do is just set that field to `#ignore` or `#string`:

```
* match response == { error: '#string' }
```

For conditional checks, you can refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50676868/143475

Also please refer this answer for some extra guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475